# Subspaces of sequences verification

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm asked to show if the following sets are a subspace of $S$, the space of
sequences.

$$B_1=\{(a_n)_n \in S|a_n=2a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2} \text{ for all } n \geq 2 \}$$

$$B_2=\{(a_n)_n \in S|a_n = 0 \text{ whenever 3 divides $n$} \}$$.

I know the properties of a subspace.

$1$. The zero vector has to be defined.

$2$. Addition has to be closed for this set.

$3$. Scalar multiplication has to be closed for this set.

I can verify addition very easily.

How would I show that if the $0$ vector and scalar multiplication is defined though? I'm not told the first term of the sequence so I'm not really sure how the various properties can be verified.

Can someone provide a hint of some kind? Thanks!

Comment: Does the zero sequence belong to $B_1$?

Comment: That's my problem. Because I don't know what the first term is, 0 should be allowed to be in the sequence right?

Comment: I suppose $\mathbf{0}=\mathbb{N}\to\{0\}$ here and it belongs to both $B_1$ and $B_2$. Scalar multiplication should be $(b_n)=\alpha (a_n)\Leftrightarrow b_n=\alpha a_n\forall n$.

Comment: $B_1$ is the set of *all* possible sequences that satisfy the given property. It means in practice that the first two elements can be whatever.

Comment: Yes I got it now. Thank you!